# "Unable to cast object of type 'PanelNamingContainer' to type 'Telerik.Web.UI.GridItem"

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, controls

I am in the process of converting a grid to a batch editing grid template for an ASP.NET application. On a `SelectedIndexChanged` event I am trying to store these controls using the `FindControl()` method but I am get an error

> Unable to cast object of type 'PanelNamingContainer' to type 'Telerik.Web.UI.GridItem'

on the 2nd line. I tried converting to just a control. I no longer get the error but then `tbIA` and `rcbGrades` end up being NULL. What can I do?

Server Side Code

```
protected void RadCB1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs e)
{
    in_c_Merit_Promotion_Flag = e.Value;
    GridDataItem item = (GridDataItem)((RadComboBox)sender).NamingContainer;
    RadNumericTextBox tbIA = (RadNumericTextBox)item.FindControl("tbIA");
    RadComboBox rcbGrades = (RadComboBox)item.FindControl("rcbGrades");
```

Client side code

```
        <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderStyle-BackColor="#00505C" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" DataField="Type_Of_Increase" HeaderText="Type Of Salary Increase" AllowFiltering="false"
                    EditFormColumnIndex="5" UniqueName="Type_Of_Increase" Visible="True" ReadOnly="False">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label  ForeColor="Black"  BorderColor="LightSlateGray" runat="server" ID="lblTypeOfIncrease" Text='<%# Bind("Type_Of_Increase") %>'></asp:Label>

                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <telerik:RadComboBox   runat="server"  MarkFirstMatch="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadCB1_SelectedIndexChanged" Skin="Web20" Width="50px"
                            AutoPostBack="true" ID="cboIncreaseType" datavaluefield="Text" datatextfield="Text" datasourceid="ObjDsSalIncType">                                
                        </telerik:RadComboBox>
                        <telerik:RadComboBox runat="server" Skin="Web20" Width="90px" MarkFirstMatch="true" AutoPostBack="false" ID="rcbGrades" Visible="false">
                        </telerik:RadComboBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" BackColor="LightSlateGray" Width="100px" ></HeaderStyle>
                    <ItemStyle BorderColor="LightSlateGray" BackColor="LightYellow" ForeColor="Black" Wrap="false" />
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>`enter code here
```

Comment: Could you provide client-side code as well?

Comment: This popular forum thread on the matter may be of great help - https://www.telerik.com/forums/unable-to-cast-object-of-type-panelnamingcontainer-to-type-telerik-web-ui-griditem

Comment: @SelimYıldız I added the client side code. I hope this helps. I think it has to do with EditItemTemplate being used with batchEdit, this is generally not a good process.